# sudoers file RHEL5

Tags: rhel5, sudo

How do I add the following to the sudoers file in RHEL5?

daemon ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/batch.php

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure giving daemon full rights to run php as root is sensible?

Comment: Cian: Ya, that too, I just wasn't in the mood to go there ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Use the visudo command for safe editing of the sudoers file, as root or with sudo:

```
visudo -f /etc/sudoers
```

If you don't know vi, you can use whatever editor you want by setting the EDITOR environment variable (assuming $VISUAL is not set), for example as root:

```
export EDITOR=/bin/nano
visudo -f /etc/sudoers
```

Although, if you don't know vi basics, maybe you shouldn't be editing your sudoers file :-)

Comment: That's "sudo visudo..."

Comment: Dennis: "as root or with sudo:"

Answer (score 0):

Literally:

```
echo 'daemon ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/batch.php' | sudo tee -a /etc/sudoers
```

Personally I'd recommend Kyle Brandt's solution.

[Edit] I've added sudo to the example as per Dennis Williamson's suggestion.

Comment: You're probably going to want a "sudo" in there somewhere.

Comment: Dennis:  It would just be: bash -c "echo '....' >> /etc/sudoers"